# How to programmatically update an app from an unknown source in Android 10

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android

Up to version `android 10`, I updated the application by downloading it through `DownloadManager` and installed through `Intent` by running it in `StartActivity`. But in `Android 10`, this no longer works. I found only one example using `PackageManager` but unfortunately nothing works. On the output `OnNewIntent` I always get the result - `PackageInstallStatus.FailureInvalid`. The example is redesigned for recording into a session from the stream http of the request, and in  original from a file. But this does not problem, I tried it from the file. Does it even work? Maybe there are some features? I also get permissions to install packages.

```
void WebUpdateApk()
    {
        Action update = async () =>
        {
            if (PackageManager.CanRequestPackageInstalls() == true)
            {
                var packageInstaller = PackageManager.PackageInstaller;
                var sessionParams = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstallMode.FullInstall);
                int sessionId = packageInstaller.CreateSession(sessionParams);
                var session = packageInstaller.OpenSession(sessionId);

                try
                {
                    var url = "http://mywebsite.com/getapk.php?apk=myapp.apk";
                    var httpResponse = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
                    try
                    {
                        if (httpResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            Stream input = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                            try
                            {
                                var packageInSession = session.OpenWrite("package", 0, -1);
                                try
                                {
                                    if (input != null)
                                    {
                                        input.CopyTo(packageInSession);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        throw new Exception("Inputstream is null");
                                    }
                                }
                                finally
                                {
                                    packageInSession.Close();
                                }
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                input.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                    finally
                    {
                        httpResponse.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                catch { }

                Intent intent = new Intent(Application.Context, Class);
                intent.SetAction("SESSION_API_PACKAGE_INSTALLED");
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
                IntentSender statusReceiver = pendingIntent.IntentSender;
                session.Commit(statusReceiver);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "No Package Installer Permission", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        };
        if (PackageManager.CanRequestPackageInstalls() == false)
        {
            RestartActivity = update;
            StartActivity(new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageUnknownAppSources,
                Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName)));
        }
        else update();
    }
    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle extras = intent.Extras;
        if ("SESSION_API_PACKAGE_INSTALLED".Equals(intent.Action))
        {
            var status = extras.GetInt(PackageInstaller.ExtraStatus);
            var message = extras.GetString(PackageInstaller.ExtraStatusMessage);
            switch (status)
            {
                case (int)PackageInstallStatus.PendingUserAction:
                    // Ask user to confirm the installation
                    var confirmIntent = (Intent)extras.Get(Intent.ExtraIntent);
                    StartActivity(confirmIntent);
                    break;
                case (int)PackageInstallStatus.Success:
                    //TODO: Handle success
                    break;
                case (int)PackageInstallStatus.Failure:
                case (int)PackageInstallStatus.FailureAborted:
                case (int)PackageInstallStatus.FailureBlocked:
                case (int)PackageInstallStatus.FailureConflict:
                case (int)PackageInstallStatus.FailureIncompatible:
                case (int)PackageInstallStatus.FailureInvalid:
                case (int)PackageInstallStatus.FailureStorage:
                    //TODO: Handle failures
                    break;
            }
            Toast.MakeText(this, "OnNewIntent status = " + status.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do not understand your code or what it should have to do with new intents but here on an Android 10 device i can just install/update apps with ACTION_VIEW and a FileProvider serving the apk file like before.

Comment: How to download apk file if there is no access to external storage?
And from apps repository I cannot install / update apps with ACTION_VIEW.

Comment: I dont know what you mean with apps repository. You can download to getFilesDir() (not with DownloadManagwr though) and getExternalFilesDir(null) without needing any permission.

Comment: `How to download apk file if there is no access to external storage?` Your app does not need that as the DownloadManager has. And if you use the uri obtained from the manager you do not even need a FileProvider i think.

Comment: Thanks for the help, figured it out! I just got confused at the beginning with these innovations. I thought that access is possible only from the `Internal storage directories`.